# Is it even possible to respect this condition is js?

Tags: javascript

I have to make a variable x that pass the condition in js.

```
if ((x==true)&&(x==false)&&(x==42)&&(x!=x)) {
  console.log("[secret_flag]"); 
} else {
  console.log("Nope");
}
```

Comment: I think i should  be `||` instead of `&&`, you can not have all the values of the `x` at the same time

Comment: There is nothing that can be true and false at the same time... nothing that can't be euqal to itself

Comment: @B001ᛦ I assume you're leaving NaN out of the "can't be equal to itself" part.

Comment: @B001ᛦ "nothing that can't be euqal to itself "? Let me introduce you to NaN

Comment: true @Taplar ;)

Comment: Side note; don't post pictures of code.  Seriously.  It typically makes helping harder (though it didn't in this case), and surely it takes longer to make the picture, upload it, and link to it, where you could have just copied and pasted it...

Comment: Yes, there is something you can do, but question unfortunately has been closed.. :)

Comment: @Keith Yes, there is, but not everyone get it ;)

Comment: @some  :), yeah, question really shouldn't have been closed.  Here is the solution for those interested -> `var a = [true, false, 42, 'x', 'y']; Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {get: () => a.shift()}); if ((x==true)&&(x==false)&(x==42)&&(x!=x)) console.log("[secret_flag]"); else console.log("Nope"); `

Comment: @Keith, I agree that it shouldn't have been closed. Let me see if I can reopen it, and then you can post your answer.

Comment: Please provide code as text, not as a picture of text. As it is, there is no [mre] in this question and is therefore off-topic.

Comment: Shouldn't the word "respect" be "expect" in the subject? (English is not my native language)

Comment: @some I'm no English major, but "respect"ing a condition as a way to express satisfying its requirements sounds reasonably natural. "expect"ing a condition doesn't seem to carry any such implication, I would get more confused with that wording.

Comment: @Klaycon Thank you, I see what you mean

Answer (score 5):

Ok,..

This is obviously a trick question that has been given to you.

What most people forget is that when you see something like - `if (x == true)` etc, `x` can represent 2 things, a variable x, but is can also represent a global x, and in the browsers case that's window.

Now `window` is an object, so that means we can attach a property getter like any other object.

So below is an example that basically creates a property x on the window that changes each time it's called, and that allows us to get our secret :)

```js
var a = [true, false, 42, 'x', 'y']; //our values

Object.defineProperty(
  window, 'x', 
  {get: () => a.shift()}); 
  
  
//now lets test.. do we get the secret flag?  
if ((x==true)&&(x==false)&&(x==42)&&(x!=x)) {
  console.log("[secret_flag]"); 
} else {
  console.log("Nope");
}
```

Comment: Since you voted to reopen the question so that you could answer it, perhaps you could take the extra step of editing the question so that it is on topic, by transcribing the code in the picture to text?